# Unable to determine composite primary key ordering.. but the ordering is there

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting this error at runtime:

*Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'X.Application.Models.ItemService'. Use the ColumnAttribute...*

But I do have the ordering set for the composite primary keys!

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace X.Application.Models
{
    public class ItemService
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Item")]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Service")]
        public int ServiceId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using EntityFramework 6.1.3.  Any ideas of where I should look?

Comment: Are you trying to create many-to-many relationship between `Item` and `Service`?

Comment: What is the definition of `Item` and `Service`?

Comment: Yes, thanks Yacoub, it is a many-to-many relationship.  An item is a device, a machine, or a network switch, etc, that can serve one or more "services".  A service is an abstraction of an application like a specific data repository, or a web application, both of which may run on several servers.  This is an asset management system for keeping track of machines and what they do.

Comment: maybe key ordering annotation has to be in the same attribute as key? I'm not sure, but you could try [Key,Column(Order = 1)]

Comment: Thanks @DevilSuichiro, I tried that already, it doesn't make any difference... and I just tried again for good measure, same error.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well and found a different cause - I'm sharing the solution just in case it benefits someone else.

One of the projects in my solution was targeting .NET 4.5.2 but when I looked at the reference I had to EF it was using the .Net 4.0 version; all of the other projects were targeting .NET 4.5.2 and the proper 452 version of EF.  After a build, the mismatched version of EF was put in the output directory and my app didn't work.

When I updated the project (and nuget's packages.config) to reference the 452 version of EF, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

The other two entities referenced from **ItemService**, which were **Service** and **Item**, referred back to **ItemService** with collection properties called **ItemServices**.

After I deleted those two properties, which were part of the many-to-many relationship that I didn't need to actually be in the model, the error went away.

```
public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int ServicId { get; set; }

    // I deleted this line
    public virtual List<ItemService> ItemServices { get; set; }

    // etc...
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    // I deleted this line too
    public virtual List<ItemService> ItemServices { get; set; }

    // etc...
}
```

Thanks everyone for the input.

Comment: This isn't a good solution in most cases. What if you need to select and navigate a collection from one of these classes?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the .NET 4.5 project accidently has referenced EntityFramework.dll from 4.0 nuget package subfolder. Simple package re-install will fix this.